# Check the value in next row in order to apply certain rules to current rows in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains two columns: id and issues; based on this dataframe, I create a new column: issues_v1 using:

```
mydf['Issue_v1']='"'+ mydf['issues']+ '"' +','
```

Here is the my sample data, sorry there is something wrong updating the screenshot, so I have to type in the following format:

```
 id         issues    issues_v1
1001           A        "A",  
1001           A        "A"    
1001          NaN       NaN   
1002           A        "A",    
1002           A        "A"    
1002          NaN       NaN
```

However, the rule I want to apply here is let the values in column B(issues) to check the values in next row, if it is NaN, then give me "A" without ",", otherwise return"A", of course, if current row is null, then return null.

Just FYI, if the logic in excel(similar) should be:

=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISBLANK(B3),""""&B2&"""",""""&B2&""","))

So how can I achieve same goal using Python? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this in two stages with `Series.mask`:

```
m = df.issues.notna()
a = df['issues'].mask(m, '"' + df.issues + '"')
b = pd.Series('', index=a.index).mask(df.issues.shift(-1).notna() & m, ',')

df['issues_v1'] = (a + b)
```

```
df    
     id issues issues_v1
0  1001      A      "A",
1  1001      A       "A"
2  1001    NaN       NaN
3  1002      A      "A",
4  1002      A       "A"
5  1002    NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I understand the logic for the code, the only question is the ' ' is show NaN in python, i will modify my question, so I should check if it is NaN or not.

Comment: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (138,) () (5,)

Comment: @what does mask means?

Comment: @Rowling It means to "hide".

Comment: ok, it means if the m is false, then return '"' + df.issues + '"', otherwise hide->NaN